# Representation of Vital Panel

Tags: hl7-fhir

Similar to Lab Panel ( Diagnostic Report with logical set of findings), Vitals are captured/displayed on a system in logical group ( BP,Height, Weight, BMI, O2 Saturation etc.).

FHIR does provide a way to group related lab panel item (wrap all related Observations under Diagnostic Report)however for vitals, what I understood is each vital will be stored as separate Observation.  This adds an extra set of logic to build the panel and need for querying multiple times.

What is the recommendation/approach around it, to present all vital entries as logical group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at this, which directly addresses the question: http://build.fhir.org/observation-vitalsigns.html

Answer (score 1):

Both lab and vital signs would be handled similarly - each individual item would be captured as an Observation with the option of grouping them in a DiagnosticReport if appropriate.  (Vitals might or might not be colated for reporting purposes, so the decision to create a DiagnosticReport would be dependent on local practice.)

Comment: In principle I understand and agree that DiagnosticReport should/can be used to club VItals however FHIR specification for DiagnosticReport category does not provide place holder for vitals.  (Refer to [link] (https://www.hl7.org/fhir/valueset-diagnostic-service-sections.html). Is this something a target for near future release of FHIR?

Comment: It's an example binding, which means it's not deemed to be complete and it's not even recommended for use.  You're completely free to add additional codes from other code system or even use a completely different code system as needed.  You could certainly submit a change request asking for "vital signs" to be added to the valueset though.